# Preventing two foreign keys to be NULL at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

In MySQL / MariaDB, how can I prevent two foreign keys from being `NULL` at the same time?
This seems quite simple at first, I used a `CREATE` statement constraint like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table` (
    `foo_id` INT UNSIGNED UNIQUE DEFAULT NULL,
    `bar_id` INT UNSIGNED UNIQUE DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `CHECK_keys_present` CHECK (
        ((`foo_id` IS NOT NULL) OR (`bar_id` IS NOT NULL)) != FALSE
    ),
    FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`) REFERENCES `Foo` (`foo_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`bar_id`) REFERENCES `Bar` (`bar_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

This solution works, as long as I manually update the values in the columns `foo_id`  and `bar_id`. In this case, the columns do not become `NULL` at the same time. However, when I delete rows from the Table `Foo` or `Bar` (which then sets the values of the foreign keys to `NULL` because of the `ON UPDATE` clauses) the constraint `CHECK_keys_present` does not trigger.

Also, I've use tried using `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers, but these do not seem to work as either.

I am using MariaDB version 10.4.8.

Also I've used the weird `` ((`foo_id` IS NOT NULL) OR (`bar_id` IS NOT NULL)) != FALSE `` construct, because just `` (`foo_id` IS NOT NULL) OR (`bar_id` IS NOT NULL) `` did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not fully an answer, because I haven't found a reference specific to `check` constraints.  However, [MariaDB does not enforce *triggers* on foreign key cascades](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/trigger-limitations/):

> The following restrictions apply to triggers.
>
> . . .
>   - Triggers are not activated by foreign key actions.

I would speculate that `check` constraints fall into the same category.

This would imply that you cannot do what you want with a cascading foreign key constraint.

Comment: Okay, this is unfortunate. I guess I will try to work around this by replacing the ON UPDATE SET NULL with a trigger that does the same thing.

Comment: Hi, is it good design to have two foreign keys that one of them can be null?

Comment: @Arash . . . There is nothing *a priori* wrong with multiple foreign keys or having `NULL` values in foreign keys.  However, you might want to ask a specific question about your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

`FOREIGN KEYs`, `TRIGGERs`, `CHECK`, etc, have only basic capabilities.  More complex things need to be done in application code or in a Stored Procedure.